# Use Label or DrawString in UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am writing my own control that will contain a panel with text, images and other media. What is the best way to render the text and images. The control may contain long texts and many images.
Should I add the text as labels and images as PictureBox or should I use the DrawString and DrawImage methods to render the text and images?
What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use labels, then you get all the labelly goodness for free.

If you use DrawString, then it'll probably be (a little bit) faster, but it's a lot more complicated if you need to deal with things like the text changing.

The OnPaint handler is a always a tricky one to write, and invalidating the client area is tricky to do efficiently.

Why not let the labels handle it all for you?

Answer (score 1):

I would use DrawString and DrawImage - you have less resources to worry about, but with added complexity.

I don't think it's that bad drawing your own strings and images once you get into it.

This is a nice introduction to it:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150116060854/http://bobpowell.net/